# Error on building OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opencv

Building my code (below) returns `error 'imread' is not a member of 'cv'`.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 11.04.
- libcv is at 2.1.0-3ubuntu1
- CMake as a build system (with only project(foo) and add_executable(foo main.cpp) in it.)

main.cpp:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     cv::Mat src = cv::imread("frame_original.png", 0);
     return 0;
 }`
```

What do I need to include to get cv::imread to work?

imread is part of OpenCV 2.1: 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread
But where is it on my system? What do I need to include? Where can I find the documentation that tells me which header file I need from OpenCV to use a specific function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include `opencv/highgui.h`.

Comment: There is no opencv/highgui.h on my system.

Comment: ok, I do not know if it helps, but if I cd to the opencv include directory, and `grep imread *` I get a hit in highgui.hpp, tha is included by highgui.h

Comment: Solved: There is a package called libhighgui2.1 and libhighgui-dev. libhighgui-dev is needed.

Comment: Isn't it strange that you have to include a gui component (which even seems to be packaged separately) to do a non-gui operation (read an image)?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to actually include the OpenCV library and the headers in your CMake configuration file.
Especially looking at [include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3ainclude_directories) for the header files and [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) for the library itself